# Styles not picked up in library components

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I have a Flex project and Flex library project. I have view components like MyGroup and MyContainer defined in the library. In the Flex project I have the Application, MyApplication, and in that a reference to a stylesheet, styles.css. The view components in the library reference styles like, "myStyle". These are defined in styles.css in the main Flex application project. These are not getting picked up or applied at runtime.

Is there something I'm doing wrong and is there a way around this? I thought about moving my stylesheet to my library project but then how do I include it (since I normally include styles in the main application). Would I have to include it in every view component?

Comment: How do you apply the stylesheet? In this kind of situation I usually create a "theme" library (with skins and a stylesheet packaged into it) and apply that as a theme on top of the Spark theme.

Comment: what @RIAstar said is how I do it also.  I make a lib that has skins, renderers and a css sheet.  then compile the css with ANT.  then in my main app call styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("Styles.swf", true); That will and does work 100% of the time.